# Rewrite URL with .htaccess and HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I have a web site where I have to use a .htaccess file to redirect all requests to index.php, where redirecting is handled.
I want to rewrite the URL, and at the same time use HTTPS. Without HTTPS it works fine.

Code from working .htaccess without HTTPS. Browser gets this input: `alert/create`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

This works fine, but without HTTPS. Browser URL becomes `http://localhost/mypage/alert/create,` and that's what I want.

I found a solution that allows me to use HTTPS:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/mypage/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Page navigation works like a charm, but browser displays the URL like this:

```
https://localhost/mypage/index.php?controller=alert&action=create&id=
```

Requests are handled like this:

```
public function __construct($urlvalues) {
    $this->urlvalues = $urlvalues;
    if ($this->urlvalues['controller'] == "") {
        $this->controller = "home";
    } else {
        $this->controller = $this->urlvalues['controller'];
    }
    if ($this->urlvalues['action'] == "") {
        $this->action = "index";
    } else {
        $this->action = $this->urlvalues['action'];
    }
}
```

I need some hints. I've been looking all over internet without solving my problem... 
If I can use .htaccess, but implement HTTPS another way, that'll be perfect too.
Server code written in PHP, running on apache2.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this in two steps. The first that you already have. And this one :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The web site works, but URL is formatted like this: https://localhost/mypage/index.php?controller=&action=&id=

Comment: You mean that the HTTPS redirect work but not with the right url ?

Comment: Have you put this RewriteRule before the RewriteRule (with your controller and action) ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Solution: Added this to .htaccess, in that order spesifically:

```
RewriteEngine on

#force https 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```